# Twitter Fabric Error

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, twitter-fabric

So I recently wanted to try out Twitter Fabric with Xcode and Swift. I have followed the steps form the Fabric application and have loaded all of the SDK and libraries into my project. However in the App delegate I am getting an error that shows [image]this...

Comment: Try changing `Twitter.self` to `Twitter()`

Comment: I fixed it I just had to update my Xcode from beta to full release version